# ASP.NET Core - Multiple Microsoft Authentication Providers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to add multiple Microsoft Authentication Providers to my ASP.NET Core Application and dynamically show one of them on the login site based on the url parameter (tenant).

I have this loop:

```
var authBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            
foreach (var microsoftExternalProvider in securityOptions.ExternalAuthentication.Microsoft)
{
    authBuilder.AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftExternalProvider.Name, microsoftOptions => {
          microsoftOptions.ClientId = microsoftExternalProvider.ClientId;
          microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = microsoftExternalProvider.ClientSecret;
          if (microsoftExternalProvider.IsSingleTenant)
          {
              microsoftOptions.AuthorizationEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{microsoftExternalProvider.TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
                microsoftOptions.TokenEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{microsoftExternalProvider.TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";   
          }
     });
}
```

I'm taking ids and secrets from array in appsettings.json.

The problem is that only the first provider set up in appsettings works. The other ones after trying to log in throw an exception:

```
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
 ---> System.Exception: The oauth state was missing or invalid.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

What should I do to make all the providers work? Couldn't find any information about adding "AddMicrosoftAccount()" more then once. That's really important for me to be able to log in from different tenants in different organizations. It can't be just one multi-tenant provider - business requirement.

Comment: **if (microsoftExternalProvider.IsSingleTenant)** is this true in both cases ?

Comment: yes, i tried all cases, 2 true, 2 false, 1 true, 1 false

Comment: I think it will not work like this. you can register only one at a time. you would have to register based on tenentid dynamically during request. check here if you get any ideas https://michael-mckenna.com/multi-tenant-asp-dot-net-core-application-tenant-specific-authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that each provider has the same default callback path - "/signin-microsoft".

The solution is to configure it in the loop like this for example:

```
microsoftOptions.CallbackPath = new PathString($"/signin-microsoft-{microsoftExternalProvider.Name}");
```

and set azure active directory app authentication web redirect url to proper url.